# Is it possible to have Xcode completion in new Swift file edition (not in a project)?

Tags: xcode, swift

Now that I found out that you can actually execute a swift program in command line by calling `swift myScript.swift` I was thinking about writing a few programs that I usually write in Python with Swift.

Although I can do that in another editor without trouble, I grew used to Xcode's completion (automatically fill existing class names, methods, constructor parameters, etc. that makes coding much easier). However, when I open a single Swift file in Xcode (without including it in a full project) with `File > New... > File...` Xcode doesn't do any completion.

Is there a special setup to do? Also, from a single open swift file, is there a way to run the script directly in a terminal from Xcode (and maybe use the debugger, etc.)?

As far as I know, Xcode is pretty useless for writing single independent swift scripts. I feel I'm missing something.

All the information I found was either about how to use the REPL in a terminal (and copy paste from a file written in any other text editor), or using Playgrounds (which are nice but incredibly slow when running simple algorithms that perform some nested loops or such), or of course making a small project, which feels way too much for some simple script writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode's code completion and related tools work from knowledge of the compile-time and run-time environment of your code... that knowledge is supplied by the compiler. Xcode doesn't know what a compiler is doing with any given file unless Xcode is the one *telling the compiler* what to do with that file — i.e. the file is in an Xcode project, which specifies how to compile, or in a playground, which implicitly provides a certain compilation/runtime environment.

You *can* create an Xcode project for a Command Line Tool (using Swift, even). That'll tell Xcode how to compile it, and thus how to interpret it for code completion and whatnot. And hitting Run in Xcode will use the debugger, with command-line I/O in the Xcode window's debug area.

(And if you're looking for other ways besides playgrounds and projects for Xcode to work with Swift files... [they do look at feature requests](http://bugreport.apple.com).)